What is the difference between nginx config files?
i have noticed that nginx has a number of configuration files such as nginx.conf in the /etc/nginx directory and 2 others one in the /etc/nginx/site-availabe called defualt and one in the /etc/nginx/site-enabled called also defulat. Does anyone knows what is the difference between all those?

The default.conf in sites-available/  is the same file as the one in sites-enabled/ as the 2nd one is a symlink. It is a template vhost you can use to create your own vhost configurations.
sites-available/ is for storing all of your configurations, whether or not they're currently enabled.
sites-enabled/ has symlinks to files in sites-available/. This allows you to selectively disable vhosts by removing the symlink.
Both are referenced in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. That file sets up all the options.

Hi thanks for the reply. So in a Ubuntu Server LTS in which i install the nginx from the ubuntu repo i must config thr default.conf or the global nginx.conf? Note that the default.conf has not an file extension is simply called defualt.

You copy default  to a new conf and add that new one to sites-available. Keep default as is so if you need a 2nd, 3rd or more vhosts you have a clean conf to start from

to a new conf with the same name of my domain name (best practice )or doesnt matter? Also there a need to tweak the global nginx.conf?
